# NULL in column used for range partitioning in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have a table partitioned by range in Postgres 10.6. Is there a way to tell one of its partitions to accept NULL for the column used as partition key?

The reason I need this is: my table size is 200GB and it's actually not yet partitioned. I want to partition it going forward, so I thought I would create an initial partition including all of the current rows, and then at the start of each month I would create another partition for that month's data.

The issue is, currently this table doesn't have the column I'll use for partitioning, so I want to add the column (initially `null`) and then tell that initial partition to hold all rows that have `null` in the partitioning key.

Another option would be to not add the column as `null` but to set an initial date value, but that would be time and space consuming because of the size of that table.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I saw that one for list partitioning, but I didn't see anything that explicit for range partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would upgrade to v11 and initially define the partitioned table with just a default partition that contains all the NULL values.

Then you can add other partitions and gradually move the data by updating the NULL values.